# Pyspark transform each row in a dataframe into multiple rows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to apache spark and am struggling to do something that seems simple.

In snowflake they  have the concept of a UDTF basically a javascript function which takes in a table and returns a table. I want to do something similar in PySpark.

Each row of the data needs to be processed. When processing a row multiple columns are read and fed into various functions. Those functions create new data which is fed into new columns. Each row is also turned into multiple rows.

For example from 1 row we might produce 3 rows each having new columns with new data.

Ideally I would like to pass in a Dataframe and return a new bigger Dataframe that has the new rows and columns.

forEach can't have a return type so it doesn't seem appropriate.
explode is a very simple function and doesn't seem appropriate.
transform seems like what I want, but it isn't clear how to iterate over all of the rows.

Is iterating over each row always a bad idea in PySpark? The dataset I'm working with is going to be very large. Many functions like collect won't work for large datasets.

Also I have mainly been focusing on using a DataFrame (not the pandas one). I have only briefly looked into RDD and pandas dataframes.

Comment: Its dependent on the transformation you intend to apply, you can derive multiple rows from a single using `explode` add new columns based on multiple other columns is also possible in Spark with `withColumn` directive which can also take in a python function as a UDF.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.